# j-query form validation code makes page redirected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Writing validation code in jquery works but if the user fills all the details and submits, then the page gets redirected.

Following is my code in form:

```
<form action="/process.php" method="post" id="address">
<div class="subscription text-left mb-4" style="color:#1E695E">
<p class="text-left mb-0"><strong>नाम</strong></p>
<input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="नाम"
                        name="full_name" required value="">
</div>
    <div class="subscription text-left mb-4" style="color:#1E695E">
    <p class="text-left mb-0"><strong>सम्पर्क नम्बर</strong></p>
<input type="text" id="defaultRegisterFormFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="सम्पर्क नम्बर "
                        name="contact" required value="">
</div>
<div class="row mb-4" style="color:#1E695E">
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-left mb-0"><strong>सडक ठेगाना</strong></
                    <!-- First name -->
                    <textarea style="resize: none;" id="defaultRegisterFormFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="ठेगाना "
                        name="address" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

<button id="confirm" class="btn btn-articles">ठेगाना पुष्टि गर्नुहोस्</button>
</form>
```

I have tried submitHandler like the following:

```
$("#confirm").validate({
 if(! $form.valid()) return false;
submitHandler: function(form) {
   var data = $('#address :input').serializeArray();

    $.post($('#address').attr('action'), data, function(info){ 
    $('#result').html(info); });
}
});

$('#address').submit(function(){

    return false;

});
```

Everything works fine but I don't want the page to be redirected.

Comment: Do you want code for redirect to another page?

Comment: @ArmanBagheri I want to validate if the user tries to send empty form but I don't want the page to be redirected.

Comment: @ArmanBagheri if I remove the validation code from above I don't get redirected but I want to check whether the form is going empty or not.

Comment: Write the code in full so I can see your form @Alisha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just prevent the form submit and call your custom function instead.

Like this:

```
<form action="/process.php" method="post" id="address" onSubmit="return false; validate();">
    [...]
</form>
```

alternatively, try this:

```
$('#address').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // do something
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
$("#confirm").validate({
    if(! $form.valid()) return false;
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $('#address :input').serializeArray();
        $.post($('#address').attr('action'), data, function(info) { 
            $('#result').html(info); 
        });
    }
});

$('#address').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

You cannot just put a conditional statement all by itself within the `.validate()` method without breaking the plugin.

```
$("#confirm").validate({
    if(! $form.valid()) return false;  // REMOVE THIS LINE
    ...
```

The `.validate()` method **only** takes `key:value` pairs representing the rules and options, and it's only attached to a selector representing the `form` container, NOT the button.

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin follows the default form action, which would include a redirect.  If you want to use ajax, then you would put that within [the plugin's `submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

> *"Replaces the default submit. **The right place** to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*

There is absolutely **no need** to write a separate `submit` handler function.

```
$("#confirm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $('#address :input').serializeArray();
        $.post($('#address').attr('action'), data, function(info) { 
            $('#result').html(info); 
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

The selector that you attach to `.validate()` **needs to match the `form`**, NOT the button.   Since the `form` tag contains `id="address"`...

```
$("#address").validate({ ....
```

---

And finally, your `button` also need to be a `type="submit"`...

```
<button id="confirm" type="submit" ....
```

---

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/ucekjzx4/1/**